# Set height of y-axis ticks in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bar-chart

since I need to add a description text to some of my y-axis titles I need to set the height of the ticks in a highcharts bar chart. Does anyone know how to get this working? Is there perhaps an automatic height calculation possible?

[image]

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
    credits: { enabled: false },
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'parameterAnalysisChart{0}'.format(chartCount),
        type: 'bar',
        height: parameters.length * categories.length * 20 + (parameters.length + 1) * 40,
        spacingRight: 20
    },
    title: { text: i18n.t('misc.valueCategory_plural') },
    xAxis: { 
        categories: xAxis
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: { text: null },
        labels: { overflow: 'justify' },
        allowDecimals: false
    },
    tooltip: { enabled: false },
    legend: { enabled: false },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#000000',
                connectorColor: '#000000',
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<strong>'+ this.series.name +':</strong> ' + this.y;
                }
            }
        },
        series: {
            minPointLength: 5,
            stickyTracking: false
        }
    },
    series: series
});
```

Comment: The tick placement has nothing whatsoever to do with what text you put next to them. The ticks are spaced according to the axis scaling and the size of the chart. You can affect their spacing by 1) making a bigger chart, 2) having fewer ticks.

Comment: I think there should be less text in the category. I mean, it is very long text and should be placed in the tooltip, in my opinion. As the comment above: categories are always equal, so you can not change `height` of that ticks/category.